# Difference between renderthreadcount and deployerthreadcount

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1-hr1

We have outscaled setup for Tridion 2013-sp1 environment with separate CM and Publishers.

We are looking into the aspects of improving the publish time so that content go live quickly. While looking for that information, I came across this question: [Rendering thread count](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11352/rendering-thread-count-publishing/11355#11355)

> What is the difference between renderthreadcount and
>   deployerthreadcount and how those will impact overall performance of
>   the publishing process?

Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `renderthreadcount`refers to the number of threads that are used by the Publisher to 'build' the content that needs to be published. For example, running each of the Components that have been published against their associated Component Templates.

The `deployhreadcount`relates to the number of threads that are used by the Transport Service to move the transport packages (zip files) to where the Deployer(s) resides.

I have given some suggestions in the following answer on how to configure these (initially) using a 'rule of thumb':
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11355/71][1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/11355/71)

Answer (score 2):

The `deploythreadcount` is used to set the number of threads that handle messages from the Publisher's Deployment Queue.

This queue is only used if you used scheduled deployment. In that case, the Transport Package is created and transported to the Deployer, but the Deployer doesn't pick it up until it receives a separate instruction to do so.

When the Transport Package is created and handed over to the Transport Service, the Publisher Service puts a scheduled message in the Deployment Queue.
When the scheduled time arrives, the message is released from the queue and handled by one of those threads.

Note that the only thing that has to be done is assemble a small Transport Package with a deploy instruction and hand that over to the Transport Service. Something that can be done within milliseconds.

So there should normally not be a need for more than one thread for this purpose.

Comment: This is really interesting information. Thanks a lot for sharing.