# How to autoscale Tridion publisher servers in AWS that are AD joined?

Tags: sdl-tridion

Do you recommend this solution(https://yatb.mitza.net/2017/03/autoscaling-publishers-in-aws.html) for publisher servers that are AD joined?

Link : [Autoscaling Publishers in AWS](https://yatb.mitza.net/2017/03/autoscaling-publishers-in-aws.html)

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange – please refer to some article which will be useful - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/852/content-management-system-with-a-separate-publisher-server/853 
https://docs.sdl.com/792149/99259/sdl-tridion-sites-9/installing-publisher-on-a-dedicated-machine 
https://docs.sdl.com/792149/675612/sdl-tridion-sites-9/troubleshooting-multiple-publishers

Comment: Please refer to this  link https://www.julianwraith.com/?p=1387 for more details on how  to scale publiser

Comment: Hi Puja. Welcome. IMO you can regard articles on yatb.mitza.net as authoritative. Meanwhile, it would help if you could expand your question to say what problem it is you are facing, what you've tried, and any further information that might lead to a good answer. Thanks.

Comment: Puja any updates on this , let us know if you are facing issues or you found any solution which you would like to share